# Plot the distance between every two points in 2 D

Tags: excel, matplotlib, ggplot2, plotly, bokeh

If I have a table with three columns where the first column represents the name of each point, the second column represent numerical data (mean) and the last column represent (second column + fixed number). The following an example how is the data looks like:
[image]

I want to plot this table so I have the following figure

[image]

If it is possible how I can plot it using either Microsoft Excel or python or R (Bokeh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I only know how to do it in ggplot2, I will answer regarding R here.

These method only works if the data-frame is in the format you provided above.

I rename your column to Name.of.Method, Mean, Mean.2.2

**Preparation**

Loading csv data into R

```
df <- read.csv('yourdata.csv', sep = ',')
```

Change column name (Do this if you don't want to change the code below or else you will need to go through each parameter to match your column names.

```
names(df) <- c("Name.of.Method", "Mean", "Mean.2.2")
```

**Method 1 - Using geom_segment()**

```
ggplot()  + 
geom_segment(data=df,aes(x = Mean, 
                         y = Name.of.Method, 
                         xend = Mean.2.2, 
                         yend = Name.of.Method))
```

So as you can see, geom_segment allows us to specify the end position of the line (Hence, **xend** and  **yend**)

However, it does not look similar to the image you have above.

The line shape seems to represent error bar. Therefore, ggplot provides us with an error bar function.

**Method 2 - Using geom_errorbarh()**

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = Name.of.Method, x = Mean)) + 
       geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = Mean, xmax = Mean.2.2), linetype = 1, height = .2)
```

Usually we don't use this method just to draw a line. However, its functionality fits your requirement. You can see that we use **xmin** and **ymin** to specify the head and the tail of the line. 
The height input is to adjust the height of the bar at the end of the line in both ends.

Comment: Many thanks, I am not familiar with R can you please tell me how I could load my data in a data frame and my data is the same shape as I provided and it is in CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `hbar` for this:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("intervals.html")

names = ["SMB", "DB", "SB", "TB"]

p = figure(y_range=names, plot_height=350)
p.hbar(y=names, left=[4,3,2,1], right=[6.2, 5.2, 4.2, 3.2], height=0.3)

show(p)
```

[image]

However [Whisker](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#whiskers) would also be an option if you really want whiskers instead of interval bars.